# How to convert the Matlab function code into Python code?

Tags: python, matlab

I have been coding in Matlab for a few years and was recently switched to Python.  How could I convert a Matlab function code into Python3 code as shown below?

```
function [estimates, model] = curvefitting(x, y, numOfpoint)

model = @expfun;

estimates = point(model, numOfpoint);

    function [sse, FittedCurve] = expfun(params)
        A = params(1);
        B = params(2);
        C = params(3);
        FittedCurve = A*(x-B).^C;
        ErrorVector = FittedCurve - y;
        sse = sum(ErrorVector .^ 2);
    end
end
```

What is `@expfun` meaning in python?  How could I make `model = @expfun` work in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing a line-by-line translation, I'd instead recommend using the tools available in Python. In this case if you are trying to perform a curve fit, first define your fit function

```
import numpy as np
def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.power(x - b, c)
```

Then you you use [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Assume these were already populated
x = np.array([...])
y = np.array([...])

# Perform curve fit
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)

# Get fitted y-values at each x point
fit_y = func(x, *popt)
```

Comment: Thank you for your translated code.  It helps me a lot.